# Link inside option tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to know how can I put a link inside an `option`tag on angular 2.

So far I have this:

```
  <select class="my-select col s12">
    <option *ngFor="let c of campanhas" value="['/disputas', c.id]">{{c.cliente_nome}}</option>
  </select>
```

the route is inside the `value` property, but when I click on it obviously nothing happens, I already tried to wrap it inside an `<a>`tag but it didn´t work. Can someone help me? Thanks

Comment: why aren't  you using [routerLink] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <select class="my-select col s12">
        <option *ngFor="let c of campanhas" [routerLink]="['/disputas',c.id]">{{c.cliente_nome}}</option>
    </select>
```

or try below code

```
 <select class="my-select col s12" #select (change)="Navigate(select.value)">
        <option *ngFor="let c of campanhas" [routerLink]="['/disputas',c.id]" value='c.id'>{{c.cliente_nome}}</option>
    </select>
```

Component.ts

```
Navigate(value)
{
   this.router.Navigate(['/disputas',value]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I've already tried it, I don't think `routeLink` works inside an `<option>' tag, when I click on the desired option nothing happens